# Why this Tooltip callback for ChartJS works and this doesn't

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I was trying to make a callback to paint my tooltip. I was trying this code here and it didn't work:

```
tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
        labelColor : function(tooltipItem, chartInstance){
            return {
                    backgroundColor : data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].backgroundColor,
                    borderColor : data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].backgroundColor
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Until I found out I need to do it like this:

```
tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
        labelColor: function(tooltipItem, chart) {
            return {
                backgroundColor : chart.config.data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].backgroundColor,
                borderColor : chart.config.data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].backgroundColor
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the difference is that I tried to access the color like this:

```
data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].backgroundColor
```

And the correct answer access it like this:

```
chart.config.data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].backgroundColor
```

I am confused because I already edited the title and legend of my tooltip, acessing my dataset without **'chart.config'**.

This works:

```
tooltips: {
   callbacks: {
       title: (tooltipItems, data) => data.labels[tooltipItems[0].index],
       label: (tooltipItems, data) => data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label + ': ' + tooltipItems.value + '%'
  }                 
}
```

So why In one case I can acess the data with **data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex]** and the other needs **chart.config.data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first snippet will also work

```
tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
        labelColor : function(tooltipItem, chartInstance){
            return {
                    backgroundColor : data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].backgroundColor,
                    borderColor : data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].backgroundColor
            };
        }
    }
}
```

here your callback function for `labelColor`  has two arguments. second argument `chartInstance` contains data and other properties you need but your are trying to access `data.datasets` instead of `chartInstance.data.datasets`.

check out this example snippet.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: 'line',

  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
    }]
  },

  // Configuration options go here
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        labelColor: function(tooltipItem, chartInstance) {
          debugger;
          return {
            backgroundColor: chartInstance.data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].backgroundColor,
            borderColor: chartInstance.data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].backgroundColor
          };
        },


        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';

          if (label) {
            label += ': ';
          }
          label += Math.round(tooltipItem.yLabel * 100) / 100;
          label += ' custom'
          return label;
        }
      }
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```